# How upload a file from a react app to the azure store emulator

Tags: javascript, azure, react-redux, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to upload a file for the azure storage emulator in a react application.

I'm using https://aka.ms/downloadazurestoragejs

This is my code:

```
const azure = require('./azure-storage.blob.js');
const devStoreCreds = azure.generateDevelopmentStorageCredentials();
let blobService = azure.createBlobService(devStoreCreds);
const serviceProperties = {
    Cors: {
        CorsRule: [{
            AllowedOrigins: ['*'],
            AllowedMethods: ['POST', 'PUT'],
            AllowedHeaders: ['*'],
            ExposedHeaders: ['*'],
            MaxAgeInSeconds: 200
        }]
    }
};
blobService.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties, function(error, result, 
response) {
    if (error) {
        alert('service failed, open browser console for more detailed 
info.');
    }
});

blobService.createContainerIfNotExists('mycont',function(error, result, 
response) {
    if (error) {
        alert('Container Failed created');
    }
    else{
        let blockSize = file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 32 ? 1024 * 1024 * 4 : 1024 
    * 512;
        const options = {
            blockSize : blockSize
        };
        blobService.singleBlobPutThresholdInBytes = blockSize;

        let finishedOrError = false;
        let speedSummary = 
        blobService.createBlockBlobFromBrowserFile("mycont", file.name, file, 
         options, function(error, result, response) {
        finishedOrError = true;
        if (error) {
            alert('Upload failed, open browser console for more detailed 
              info.');
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            alert('ok.');
        }
    });
}
});
```

but I'm getting this error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (CORS not enabled or no matching rule found for this request.)

Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/?comp=properties&restype=service: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Comment: Any update? You could accept one useful answer or post method you found valid.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is used to set whether the service you request allows your js script from browser in different domain. It means all requests sent from browser need CORS check, including  `setServiceProperties`.

So you need to create a separate file to execute CORS settings as a back-end operation. For example, you can use nodejs to run your `setServiceProperties`.

1. Install [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/).
2. In one folder, open any command line tools like cmd on windows, input `npm install azure-storage` to install storage module for script to use.
3. Create one setcors.js file in this folder.

   ```
   const azure = require('azure-storage');
   const devStoreCreds  = azure.generateDevelopmentStorageCredentials();
   const blobService = azure.createBlobService(devStoreCreds);

   const serviceProperties = {
       Cors: {
           CorsRule: [{
               AllowedOrigins: ['*'],
               AllowedMethods: ['POST', 'PUT','HEAD'],
               AllowedHeaders: ['*'],
               ExposedHeaders: ['*'],
               MaxAgeInSeconds: 200
           }]
       }
   };

   blobService.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties, function(error, result, response) {
       if (error) {
           console.log(error);
       }
   });
   ```
4. In cmd, input `node setcors.js` to run your script. No message means it executes successfully.
5. If you got exception prompt you to get latest version [storage emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#get-the-storage-emulator), just follow the link to install it.

Note that method `HEAD` is included in `AllowedMethods` because it's used in `createContainerIfNotExists`.

Also you can use [storage-explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) to set CORS.

Storage Accounts->(Development)->right click on Blob Container. Configure CORS settings as your wish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Jerry Liu said above, we need to config CROS of azure store emulator.

We can do as below:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";

# config

$AccountName='your account name'
$AccountKey='your account key'

# derived config

$BlobEndpoint="http://127.0.0.1:10000/$($AccountName)"
$QueueEndpoint="http://127.0.0.1:10001/$($AccountName)"
$TableEndpoint="http://127.0.0.1:10002/$($AccountName)"

$ConnectionString = "" +
    "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" + 
    "BlobEndpoint=$($BlobEndpoint);" +
    "QueueEndpoint=$($QueueEndpoint);" +
    "TableEndpoint=$($TableEndpoint);" +
    "AccountName=$($AccountName);" +
    "AccountKey=$($AccountKey)"

# authentication

    $Context = New-AzureStorageContext `
    -ConnectionString $ConnectionString

# cors rules
$CorsRules = (@{
    AllowedHeaders=@("*");
    AllowedOrigins=@("*");
    ExposedHeaders=@("Content-Length");
    MaxAgeInSeconds=60*60*24;
    AllowedMethods=@("Get", "Post")
})

Set-AzureStorageCORSRule `
    -ServiceType Table `
    -Context $Context `
    -CorsRules $CorsRules

# check
Get-AzureStorageCORSRule `
    -ServiceType Table `
    -Context $Context
```

Similar thread for your reference:

[How do i add a CORS rule to the Azure Storage Emulator with HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659780/how-do-i-add-a-cors-rule-to-the-azure-storage-emulator-with-http)