# How to configure self service password reset in the new Azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-active-directory, azureportal

I know there are a lot of examples over the web that explain how the administrator of an Azure AD can configure self service password reset for users in the classic portal. However, I am working on the new Azure portal and am not sure if the same feature is available in the new portal. If it is possible then please point me to some example explaining the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve password reset in Azure AD B2C.

The simplest one is via the Sign-In Policy which uses the out-of-the-box password reset. This is the one I believe you're asking about. To enable that one in the new portal:

1. Go to the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com)
2. On the left menu, click on **More Services >**
   [image: More services]
3. Search for **Azure Active Directory** and click on it.
   [image: Azure Active Directory]
4. Select **Password Reset**
5. The Properties blade will open automatically, there should be a single Self Service Password Reset Enabled button, change it to **Everybody** and click on **Save**.
   [image: SSPR]

Alternatively, you can configure self-service password reset via the Sign-up/sign-in Policy which requires extra work by the application, but allows you greater flexibility with regards to customizing the UI. For more information on that approach, check out this other StackOverflow post: [ad b2c self service password reset link doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497158/ad-b2c-self-service-password-reset-link-doesnt-work/41798673#41798673)