# azure-ad-b2c forgot password URL does not work

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

It seems that the "Forgot your password?" link on the Azure B2C Sign in page does not invoke the defined Password Reset Policy when using a SignUp/SignIn policy.

Is Microsoft working on resolving this issue? or has anyone found a way to get the password reset policy to run from the link?

I can run the  Password Reset endpoint from within the Azure B2C portal, but can not get to this endpoint from my application. I get sent to https:///.auth/login/aad/callback with a "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." message.

It seems like the Azure B2C workflow is wrong for the Forgot password URL. Does anyone have an idea when this might get fixed? I am using a Sign Up/Sign In policy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ad b2c self service password reset link doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497158/ad-b2c-self-service-password-reset-link-doesnt-work)

Comment: I have tried the code in the referenced post and it does not work for me. I still get "You do not have permission to view this directory or page" message. IMHO - I should not have to hit my code to reset the password, the process is already in place in the B2C policy.

Comment: Can you update your question w/ the type of policy?  Sign-in/Sign-up or just sign-in?

Comment: It is a SignUp/SignIn policy. When I switch it to be just SignIn I can change the password and all is fine, but we want the dual policy. I am wondering if it is my Issuer Url in Active Directory Authentication. https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my B2C Tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_TeamEdSignUpIn Should I have the policy appended to the end like this?

Comment: The forgot password in a SignUp/SignIn policy ["... requires the application to do some extra work"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497158/ad-b2c-self-service-password-reset-link-doesnt-work)