# Error on forgot password on custom signin/signup policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm having this error when y press on the forgot password button on my custom signup/signin policy:

http://localhost:4200/?error=access_denied&error_description=AADB2C90118%3a+The+user+has+forgotten+their+password.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+1a6f0897-8e02-4a29-a413-209649f5e5bb%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2017-10-25+20%3a52%3a25Z%0d%0a

If I access directly to my custom reset password policy it works.

Is there some configuration that I should add to my policies to make them work?

Thanks in advance!

Germán

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ad b2c self service password reset link doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497158/ad-b2c-self-service-password-reset-link-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design.

Your end application is expected to handle this forgot password "error" by invoking your password reset policy.

An example of this can be found in [the B2C-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet-SUSI sample](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet-SUSI).

See [the Startup.Auth class](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet-SUSI/blob/complete/WebApp-B2C-DotNet/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs) for how the `AADB2C90118` error is handled.

Comment: I have a new question about this: this works on my mobile application. But on a web page I can't capture the error because it redirects to azure.
Right now we manage it hiding the reset password from the form retreived from azure. And then we add a new link below to our custom reset password policy.
Can we manage this in a better way?

Comment: Hi @GermánSvriz: What do you mean you "can't capture the error because it redirects to Azure"?