# ASP.NET Core: Azure AD B2C self service password reset (sign-up/sign-in policy)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I research whole internet and didn't find any approach, that hooks up into the AuthenticationFailed notification and redirects to your own PasswordReset controller action.
Here is a good example for [asp.net framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497158/azure-ad-b2c-self-service-password-reset-link-doesnt-work) but it not suite for me. I need the same for ASP.NET Core WebAPI project.
Here is another [link with example core project](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp) but really can't figure out how to implement it into my own project. I am using bearer token authorization.
Does anybody have any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is [enable self-service password reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-sspr). Then users will se a "Forgot your password?" link on the sign-in page. If you need more control you can [create a password reset policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-password-reset-policy).

Comment: thanks for the reply but now I am able to see Forgot password link, when I pick it, I see an error from my own domain. Here is how it looks like: https://www.screencast.com/t/VY6rcSVyg 
So I make a conclusion that I has wrong config. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, its handeld in the faq: Instead, the error code AADB2C90118 is returned to your app. Your app needs to handle this error code by invoking a specific password reset policy. For more information, see a sample that demonstrates the approach of linking policies

Comment: great ! Does Microsoft has any examples how to do that in asp.net core?

Comment: I don't want hard code full password reset url as well. Do we have another way to do that ?  thanks

Comment: This article covers the password reset in aad b2c for .net core 2.0 (at the bottom):  https://dzimchuk.net/setting-up-your-asp-net-core-2-0-apps-and-services-for-azure-ad-b2c/ . Password reset policy is similar to the signup policy so why don't you want to hard code them? Its already an abstraction since you can configure them....