# Can we directly provide a policy name for Forgot your password link on Azure AD B2C SignIn Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using custom SignUp/SignIn policies and custom UI.

I have been through the posts on stackoverflow for "Forgot Your Password" functionality, which says the calling application need to read the error code and redirect to PasswordReset Policy.

When I Inspected the html, I found a href for forgotpassword link which is pointing to my signUpSignIn Policy.

```
<div class="password-label">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <a id="forgotPassword" tabindex="2" href="/domain.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin/api/CombinedSigninAndSignup/forgotPassword?csrf_token=xxxxxx&StateProperties=xxx & p=B2C_1A_signup_signin">Forgot your password?</a>
 </div>
```

Is there any way that I can call the PasswordReset policy from the href directly, instead of catching the error code, as I am using custom policies.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you link "been through the posts on stackoverflow for "Forgot Your Password""?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure AD B2C self service password reset link doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497158/azure-ad-b2c-self-service-password-reset-link-doesnt-work)

Comment: Hi spottedmahn, the reference you gave is one the posts I have been through, and have my code working this route.

Comment: But looking to see if it can be achieved with a direct link with custom policies

Answer (score 0):

You **can** send the user directly to the password reset policy from your application.

You **can't** send the user directly from a Sign-In/Sing-Up policy to the Password Reset Policy as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497158/azure-ad-b2c-self-service-password-reset-link-doesnt-work).

---

UserVoice: [Go Direct to Password Reset from Sign-In/Sign-Up](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/33494830-go-direct-to-password-reset-from-sign-in-sign-up)