# AAD B2C: After "reset password" from Azure Portal the B2C users cannot change it while loging in by SignIn policy URL

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

AAD B2C: After "reset password" from Azure Portal the B2C users cannot change it while loging in by SignIn policy URL.

If I (as AAD B2C admin) reset password to some user (type of Member in AAD) then thit user cannot change password using Sing-In Policy URL - the login form doesn't accept temporary password.

But if the user tries to log in to portal.azure.com with it's UPN and temp password - then password change works fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure AD B2C self service password reset link doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497158/azure-ad-b2c-self-service-password-reset-link-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a known issue](https://github.com/twright-msft/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-limitations.md#issues-with-admin-initiated-password-reset-on-the-azure-portal) that is related to administrators resetting passwords for local account users via the Azure Portal.

It is recommended that administrators reset passwords for local account users using [the Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#ResetUserPassword).

Comment: Currently facing the following: User's password must comply with some constraints, including special chars, which auto-generate password admin seems not to be able to create. Thus when the user tries to sign-in using a non-compliant password gets an invalid username or password error and can't proceed. Issue better detailed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1023652/azure-b2c-reset-password-by-admin-do-not-comply-wi.html

Comment: However, couldn't find anything similar to it on the limitations page.