# password reset in asp.net mvc app with ad b2c

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am not able to find proper documentation on how to get started with the scenarios below:

1. Forgot password. I have setup the reset password policy in Azure AD B2C and the user can click Forgot Password which redirects the user to a controller action in my app. But I'm not really sure what to do from here.
2. Reset password from user profile in my app. In my app, I would like the user to be able to click "Reset Password" which would redirect the user to having their password reset.

For both of the scenarios above, I would like Azure AD B2C to handle the password reset by asking the user for their email and then emailing them the password reset link and then handling the password reset appropriately. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure AD B2C self service password reset link doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497158/azure-ad-b2c-self-service-password-reset-link-doesnt-work)

Comment: sorry no it doesn't. it doesn't work for me at all. I have it configured like it mentioned in startup.cs which points it to an action method, which has this code: HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
        new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" }, Startup.PasswordResetPolicyId);

Comment: Hi @Riz, Have you found a solution for the second scenario?

Answer (score 0):

There are two use cases for password reset:

If you click on the link in the signup / signin page, you get the error code AADB2C90118 which is returned to your application. Your application then needs to run a specific user flow that resets the password. Refer a [simple ASP.NET sample](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet-SUSI) that demonstrates the linking of the user flows.

If the user has already signed in, you can simply provide a link. This link invokes the [password reset policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow) that is configured on the B2C side.